# Can I change the audio device of a specific app via command line?

Tags: windows, audio

I use multiple different virtual audio devices on my PC to split my Audio. (Virtual Cables)

I have a problem with one app where every time I launch it, it reverts the audio device of the app back to the default windows audio device. So everytime I launch it I have to go into the App Volume and Device settings to change it to its proper device.

I'm looking for a command line or script solution for this to automate the process. I'd prefer if the app didn't revert to the default device but I don't think I can fix that...

Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps try [`SoundVolumeView /SetAppDefault ...`](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html#command_line)